# Redux will not trigger rerender when copying an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

The code below triggers a rerender:

```
builder.addCase(fetchGameInfo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.players = action.payload.players;
      state.gameTime = action.payload.gameTime;
      state.error = "";
      state.loading = "idle";
    });
```

However, the code below does not trigger a rerender:

```
builder.addCase(fetchGameInfo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = {...state, ...action.payload};
      state.error = "";
      state.loading = "idle";
    });
```

I suspect it has something to do with object creation and duplication of some sort? Is there a way to combine two objects AND trigger a rerender within React? I'd rather not manually "copy" the data for each key like in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> Redux toolkit will not trigger rerender when copying an object

Yes this is [because it use immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)

On your second example as you change the reference of state your should return it

```
builder.addCase(fetchGameInfo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = {...state, ...action.payload};
      state.error = "";
      state.loading = "idle";
      return state;
});
```